# Plotting binary variable frequency for multiple variables across 2 groups

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 4 of binary variable (4 genes that are either mutated 1 or not 0), these variables are observed for 2 populations (either TPLL or LNH-T)

The data looks like so:

structure(list(Diag = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("LNH-T", "LPL-T"), class = "factor"),
JAK1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),
JAK3 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"),
IL2R = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "0", class = "factor"), STAT5B = structure(c(1L,
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), levels = c("0",
"1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df",
"tbl", "data.frame"))

[image: Dataset]

I would like to plot the percentage of mutation for each gene in each population with both populations (TPLL and LNH-T) side by side all on the same plot

I have tried several ggplot and basic plot functions but haven't been successful so far

```
ggplot(ds) + aes(x=JAK1) + geom_histogram(stat ="count", fill="steelblue",aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)))
```

I tried this but I don't really need the negative frequency, only the positive. Also both populations are mixed right now and I would like to have all 4 genes and both populations on the same plot.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome! Please provide sample data as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You can use `dput`. That way, it's less work (and error prone) to help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Apologies ! I added the deconstructed data using dput in the main body. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

- create summary dataframe (`d` being your example dataframe)

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(tidyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    
    d_mutation_perc <- 
      d |>
      pivot_longer(-Diag,
                   names_to = 'gene',
                   values_to = 'is_mutation'
                   ) |>
      summarise(mutated_perc = 100 * sum(is_mutation == 1) / n(), .by = c(Diag, gene))
    
    # A tibble: 8 x 3
      Diag  gene   mutated_perc
      <fct> <chr>         <dbl>
    1 LPL-T JAK1           9.52
    2 LPL-T JAK3          52.4 
    3 LPL-T IL2R           0   
    4 LPL-T STAT5B        61.9 
    5 LNH-T JAK1           0   
    6 LNH-T JAK3           0   
    7 LNH-T IL2R           0   
    8 LNH-T STAT5B        22.2
```

plot:

```
    d_mutation_perc |>
      ggplot(aes(gene, mutated_perc, group = Diag)) +
      geom_col(aes(fill = Diag), position = 'dodge')
```

[image: column plot of percentages]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's excatly what I was looking for !